# Why SessionMap is not instantiated?

Tags: java, session, struts2, struts2-interceptors

The first time a member registers, the session needs to be set, which normally happens in login, so I thought I'd reuse the `LoginAction` without routing to it.
But the `sessionmap` isn't getting instantiated.

```
member logging in is: model.hibernate.Member@549c8a8c
session map not instantiated
```

RegisterAction

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    private String username, password, email;

    SessionMap<String,Object> sessionmap;  
     MemberDAO mdao = new MemberDAO();
     UsersDAO udao = new UsersDAO();
     Users user = new Users();
     Member member = new Member();



    public RegisterAction() {
        this.email = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.username = "";
    }

   // ...setters/getters...



    public String execute() {



            udao.addUserToDatabase(newUser);

            Member newMember = new Member(username, password);
            mdao.addMemberToDatabase(newMember);
            member = newMember;

            // perform first login (to set session member and role).
            // this could be done by sending to login action. 
            // but then would have to track that it was first login.  this is quick fix. 
            LoginAction firstLogin = new LoginAction(member);   
            firstLogin.setSession(sessionmap);
            String firstLoginAttempt = firstLogin.execute();
            String resultString = "";
            if(firstLoginAttempt.equals(SUCCESS)){resultString = SUCCESS;}
            else{            
                    addActionError("First login attempt didnt work");
                    resultString = ERROR;
            }


            return resultString; // send user to quiz or show error
         }else {
            // cant add user
             addActionError("Username already taken. Please choose another.");
             return ERROR;
         }
    }

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        sessionmap=(SessionMap) map;  
    }
}
```

LoginAction

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    private String username, password;

     MemberDAO mdao = new MemberDAO();
     Member member = new Member();
     SessionMap<String,Object> sessionmap;  


    public LoginAction() {
        this.password = "";
        this.username = "";
    }

    public LoginAction(Member m) {
        this.member = m;
        this.password = member.getPassword();
        this.username = member.getUsername();

    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String execute() {

        // checks that credentials match db


        setLoggedInMember(member);
        setLoggedInRole(member);

    }


    public String logout(){  
            if(sessionmap!=null){  
                sessionmap.invalidate();  
            }  
        return "success";  
    }  

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {

        sessionmap=(SessionMap) map;  

    }
protected void setLoggedInMember(Member m){
    System.out.println("member logging in is: "+m.toString());
    try{
        if(sessionmap!=null){
    sessionmap.put("member",m.toString());
        }
        else{System.out.println("session map not instantiated");}
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

}

public Member getLoggedInMember(){
    return (Member) sessionmap.get("member");
}


protected void setLoggedInRole(Member member) {
    if(member.getAdmin() != null)
        sessionmap.put("role", "admin");
    else if(member.getAgent()!=null)
        sessionmap.put("role", "agent");
    else if(member.getUsers()!=null)
        sessionmap.put("role", "user");
    else
        addActionError("Unknown member role");
}

public String  getLoggedInRole(){
    return (String) sessionmap.get("role");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have [`servletConfig`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/servlet-config-interceptor.html) interceptor referenced in the action configuration.

> An interceptor which sets action properties based on the interfaces
>   an action implements. For example, if the action implements
>   `ParameterAware` then the action context's parameter map will be set on
>   it.
>
> This interceptor is designed to set all properties an action needs if
>   it's aware of servlet parameters, the servlet context, the session,
>   etc. Interfaces that it supports are:
>
> ```
> ServletContextAware
>
> ServletRequestAware
>
> ServletResponseAware
>
> ParameterAware
>
> RequestAware
>
> SessionAware
>
> ApplicationAware
>
> PrincipalAware
> ```

---

The capability of this interceptor to inject the servlet stuff objects to the action bean.

Note, this interceptor is included in the `defaultStack`, which is used by default if you don't reference any of interceptors. If you override the interceptors in the action config the `defaultStack` disappears.

Comment: well i havent overridden any interceptors yet. so the default stack should be working..

Comment: but for now, i have settled with just reimplementing the session mgmt that was in login.

Comment: or maybe i couldve also gotten the session map like this
`Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();` which worked for me elsewhere.

Comment: this is also a way to get the session map, but implementing `SessionAware` is preferable.

Answer (score -1):

RegisterAction

```
Member newMember = new Member(username, password);//newMember having username,password object
Member member = new Member();
LoginAction firstLogin = new LoginAction(member);
firstLogin.execute();
```

in RegisterAction you passed Member Object(like as Member < username , password > )

LoginAction.class

```
 public String execute() {
    //if you received member object here.
    //retrieve your username,password here like this
     //Your mentioned model.hibernate.Member@549c8a8c -->Object Reference value

     member.getUsername();
     member.getPassword();



    setLoggedInMember(member);
    setLoggedInRole(member);

}
protected void setLoggedInMember(Member m){
    System.out.println("member logging in is: "+m.getUsername());


}
```